# Print HTML to PDF while retaining hyperlinks

Tags: pdf, html

I'm trying to create a PDF document from an HTML document.

Of course it's easy to do this using the built-in PDF Printer, however, this does not retain hyperlinks.

I've tried [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which looked very promising, but it crashes on every attempt.

Is anyone aware of any other options for generating a PDF document from an HTML document while retaining URL links?

Comment: I can't confirm if this works, but something you might consider is converting from HTML to LaTeX. Then convert from LaTeX to PDF since LaTeX is a common way to create hyperlinks in a PDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found an answer over on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/145906/searching-for-free-html-to-pdf-software/145909#145909): [wkpdf](http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/)

Free, works perfectly. All hyperlinks retained.

Comment: Also good is wkhtmltopdf. Both of these tools are available via Homebrew on Mac OS.

Comment: no longer installs; author seems to have purposefully disabled installation in anticipation of future incompatibility; WTF?

Comment: There is an incompatibility with Yosemite from what I gather.

Answer (score 7):

The built-in Safari browser seems to do this when you do `File -> Print -> PDF -> Save as PDF`, it works for me as of Version 6 of Mac Safari.

Comment: True, and this has worked in the same nice way in older versions too. [OmniWeb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/) did so too, but I have not used that for years, so things might have changed.

Comment: Does it retain the hyperlinks for you?

Comment: Is there a way to automate this, like what wkpdf used to offer?

Comment: @Ian For me this retains "external" hyperlinks, but not links to within-page named anchors.

Comment: The built-in Safari browser preserves link *formatting* (e.g., blue underlined display text), but not clickable *links* (although Preview and Acrobat will automatically interpret URLs as clickable, even if they are not actually hyperlinked in the source document).

Comment: Works on windows 11, chrome 100

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html).

In Acrobat, go to File-> Create PDF-> From File. Select your HTML doc, let it do a bit of work, and then use File-> Save As to save it.

All hyperlinks will be intact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a non-$200 option?

Comment: @Ian I'm sure there is, but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: After looking for two days, I've yet to find one, for Mac or Windows, that retains hyperlinks that have anchor text. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but just found out if you open the .html in Microsoft Word and then save as pdf for online distribution, then the link works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried dompdf in the past and has worked very well for me. [dompdf PHP](http://webtricksandtreats.com/html-to-pdf-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Save as PDF" browser plugins:

Chrome plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kpdjmbiefanbdgnkcikhllpmjnnllbbc

Firefox plugin:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-as-pdf/

Both are free, but developed by a commercial company http://pdfcrowd.com.
I tried the FF plugin, and except for some minor layout overlapping in the converted PDF document, all hyperlinks were clickable and working.

Answer (score 0):

http://pdfcrowd.com only works, if the link is public - so no printing of pages, where you are logged in.

Comment: Yeap. I concur. If you print, say, a Gmail message or a SaaS wordpress site (in my case) where I'm logged in, it only prints the login page even though I'm NOT in the login page.