# Convert HTML to PDF with page margins and hyperlinks

Tags: safari, pdf, preview, printing, html

Unfortunately, it would appear that Safari doesn't support [CSS2 page margins from CSS2 recommendation circa 1998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542320/margin-while-printing-html-page), whereas all other major browsers now do.

However, when printing out an HTML page, it would seem like it is only Safari (or at least some versions of it on some systems) that preserves the hyperlinks into the PDF document, whereas all other browsers (SeaMonkey, Firefox, Google Chrome) only preserve the decoration.

Is there any way to print a rather complex HTML document into PDF without losing the hyperlinks, but ensuring narrow margins?

There's a related question, but it's simply after the hyperlinks, without any regards to the page margins — [Print HTML to PDF while retaining hyperlinks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/print-html-to-pdf-while-retaining-hyperlinks).

Comment: You do not want to use Adobe Acrobat ?

Comment: Give us a sample of your document if it is public.

Comment: @Buscar웃, would I have to pay for Adobe Acrobat?  I'd like a free solution.  I've tried adding a new paper size in Safari, with zero margins, but it seems to have no effect on the margins in Safari (it does in SeaMonkey).  No, the document is not public.

Comment: Is it one time deal if not might be worth getting Acrobat. Also try they online services.

Comment: @Buscar웃, the whole point is that I want to be able to have a say of how stuff is formatted; I can already do better than the online services by simply printing directly from Safari, and ignoring the huge page margin at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [wkpdf](http://plessl.github.io/wkpdf/):

```
sudo gem install wkpdf;wkpdf -s file.html -m 10 file.pdf
```

It retains links and you can specify margin sizes with `-m`.

Comment: It doesn't install; `gem -v` returns `1.3.6` (wkpdf requires >=1.3.3), `sudo gem install wkpdf` returns `ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository` `ERROR:  could not find gem wkpdf locally or in a repository`.

Comment: actually, it might be related to my wifi tethering provider proxy server blocking my stuff... :-)  is there an easy way to specify a socks proxy or a different user-agent or port? :)

Comment: I'm accepting this because it works as far as the question is worded, although it'd be nice to have the ability to still print the header/footer stuff as the browser does.  Thanks for your help; I looked at wkpdf prior to asking this question, but its homepage -- http://plessl.github.io/wkpdf/#usage -- did not indicate the ability to control the margins, hence was my question.

Comment: Hm, there's also WeasyPrint, which is not OS-X-specific, but it doesn't seem to work as good as wkpdf (they implement their own rendering, and seem to be missing some features, even though they also supposedly implement those that aren't supported by WebKit, e.g. specific to printing and paged media).

Comment: Sadly, this no longer seems to work on 10.9; my understanding is that, according to http://plessl.github.io/wkpdf/, due to potential future issues the author has disabled installation through `gem`. :-(

Comment: So, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/29223418/1122270, with the gem being `yanked`, an extra step of `wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin.gem` is necessary; additionally, on OS X 10.9, `sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem install wkpdf` must be used in place of the default `2.0`.  And OS X 10.10 is not supported.